# Android: Sharing "EXTRA_TEXT" caption with Image

Tags: java, android, android-intent, mobile, android-sharing

I have implemented sharing feature using Intents and it's working properly. I'm sharing a bitmap by converting it to a file. But I want to add an extra caption along with the post when users share it. I tried this:

```
Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, " Shared via App"); //this part doesnt work
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + sharefile));
//sharefile is my image file. It gets shared properly. 
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Product"));
} catch (Exception e) {                         


}
```

But it doesn't share the CAPTION. It shares the Image successfully.

Comment: What application are you sharing the image and caption to?

Comment: Facebook, instagram, multiple :) There's a chooser, so the user decides @Tanis.7x

Answer (score 2):

Try **Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE** instead Intent.ACTION_SEND

Answer (score 0):

Other applications determine whether or not they support attaching a caption to an image or not. If you are experiencing issues with a specific platform ignoring the `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` that you pass with the image, you will need to contact the developers of that application for support.

Facebook is one example of a platform that does not support attaching a caption or description to an image. [Here's a bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423/) requesting this feature with the response from the Facebook team. In this case, attaching a message would violate Facebook's platform policies.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line:

```
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, caption);
```